# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: timeformationBD.formations index: description_1 dup key: { : null }

Tags: node.js, web

**hello , plz any one help me

i am getting duplicate key error while doing the POST action
i tried several to correct them but I do not understand what is happening**

**Error** *MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: timeformationBD.formations index: description_1 dup key: { : null }*

**this is my formation.route**

```
 var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var Formation = require('../models/formations');

    router.post('/', function(req, res){
        var newFormation = {
            name: req.body.name,
            position : req.body.position,
            department : req.body.department,
            salary: req.body.salary
        }
         Formation.addFormation(newFormation,function(err,formation){
             if(err) throw err;
             res.json(formation);
         });
     })

     module.exports = router

;
```

**this is my formation.models**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var FormationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    position : String,
    department : String,
    salary : String
})

var Formation = module.exports = mongoose.model('Formation', FormationSchema);


module.exports.addFormation = function(newFormation, callback){
    Formation.create(newFormation, callback);
}
```

**this is my app.js ( endpoint )**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config/database');

const User = require('./models/user');
const Formation = require('./models/formations');



mongoose.connect(config.database ,  { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
console.log('connected to database... ' + config.database);
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
console.log('database error'+err);
});




/*mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/hello', { useNewUrlParser: true });
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log('we are connected!');

});*/



const app = express();
const users = require('./routes/users');
const formations = require('./routes/formations');

//port number
 const port = 3001;

//cors middleware
 app.use(cors({
     origin: 'http://localhost:4200'
 }));
 //passwport middelware
 app.use(passport.initialize());
 app.use(passport.session());
 require('./config/passport')(passport); //pour implémenter fichier passport.js

 //set static folder
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));




//BodyParser middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/users', users);//hedhiya ki nekteb /users barka f url yemchili direct lel const users = require('./routes/users'); fichier hedhka

app.use('/formations', formations); 

//c un route 
//just meloul 7atineha bch ntastiw beha 
//index route
 app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('invalid endpoint');
});



//start Server
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

 app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port' +port);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have issue similar to one described in the following post.

https://www.opentechguides.com/askotg/question/16/mongodb-create-unique-index-e11000-duplicate-key-error-collection-dup-keynull.

```
Answered By Sonja on opentechguides.com.

When a new index is created, all existing documents must have one. If they don't, a null value is assigned.

When you create a unique index there can be only one (or none) pre-existing document without that index.

If there are multiple documents with that index missing, then index build fails. Null value cannot be assigned to more than one documents because of the unique constraint.

Solution: Remove pre-existing documents without an index or assign unique values manually.
```

You need to drop old indexes https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/, and then generate new again. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.reIndex/

I am not sure though why it didn't assign index in first place.

Comment: thank you for your help  and  I solved the problem when I repeated all my crude again

Comment: @khouloudES 

Comment: @khouloudES If my answer helped you can you accept it?